# Can't include scripts/css on AppFog Node App

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, include, appfog

I'm trying to create a Node App with AppFog, I started by including the `index.html` in my `app.js`

```
var http = require('http'),
fs = require('fs');


fs.readFile('./index.html', function (err, html) {
    if (err) {
        throw err; 
    }       
    http.createServer(function(request, response) {  
        response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});  
        response.write(html);  
        response.end();  
    }).listen(8000);
});
```

The index is then including scripts and css

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="script/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="base.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<script src="Bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<!-- Main CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
```

The `index.html` is loading properly but the scripts and the styles aren't. 
The site is [THIS](http://maluk.aws.af.cm) if you want to check, from the console you can see that each file returns the index.html instead of the JS code or CSS style.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using Express NodeJS Framework and let him redirect the user to the correct page.